# AWS Market Place Adobe FMS Server 5.x Error in log file

Tags: adobe, flash-media-server

I have setup a Adobe Media Server 5 Extended from the market place. The document is not great but you get by. I see in the log file the following line constantly being repeated, and my flex client is not connecting to the server, gets connection timeout. I have opened all the right ports 1935, 443, 80, 8143 1111. Please point me to the documentation to setup a application. Thanks.

```
Javascript[2225]: Connection rejected by server. Reason : [ Server.Reject ] : (_defaultRoot_, _defaultVHost_) : Application (dictation) is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer it myself. It was jut RTFM type question, but the manual was not very clear or good. If your using the AWS market place FMS 5 server, the application directory is NOW in /mnt/applications, I missed that. I created my asc application /mnt/applications/dictation and restarted the server all was good.

One issue that stumped me is the permissions issue. Make sure the streams directory has the right permissions that it all works. Now looking back it seems very easy to install. Good luck.

Interestingly when my permissions were not right on the streams directory, I kept getting mic permission issue. Client side on the browser kept telling me I dont have permission for the mic.